# How to set a time out like Serial.setTimeout() for Serial.read()?

Tags: serial, time, uart

I read a comment form [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=439572.0):

"Serial.setTimeout() sets the maximum milliseconds to wait for serial data when using Serial.readBytesUntil(), Serial.readBytes(), Serial.parseInt() or Serial.parseFloat(). It defaults to 1000 milliseconds."

According to the [latest webpage](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/settimeout/),

"Serial functions that use the timeout value set via Serial.setTimeout():

```
Serial.find()

Serial.findUntil()

Serial.parseInt()

Serial.parseFloat()

Serial.readBytes()

Serial.readBytesUntil()

Serial.readString()

Serial.readStringUntil()
```

"

So apparently, there's no direct indication to set a timeout option for Serial.read().

How to set a time out like Serial.setTimeout() for Serial.read()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set timeout for read(), but you can use readBytes() to read one byte.

```
byte b;
int count = Serial.readBytes(&b, 1); // read one byte with timeout
if (count) { // 0 or 1
  Serial.write(b); //echo
}
```

Comment: So Serial.read() and Serial.readBytes() were like two different class of objects?

Comment: no. read() is the basic function. readBytes() is a function too and implemented with use of read().